# Resize div when mouse hover on top of another one

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

im currently working on a project for my company and im pretty new to html and css.
my question is this, im trying to make a menu resize its size when i hover on top of it so the submenu is open.
the div .itemMenu should go from width 100% to 50%, so the submenu (.itemSubmenu) can be shown

here are some pics
[image]
[image]
[image]

and this is my code

```css
    /* Variables */
    
     :root {
        --Gray: #323a3a;
        --DarkBlue: #123B79;
        --LightBlue: #18A5A7;
        --LightGray: #D9D9D9;
        --White: white;
    }
    /* Body tools */
    
    body {
        margin: 0 auto;
        user-select: none;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: black;
    }
    /* Container */
    
    .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    /* Left DIV  */
    
    .left {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        width: 20%;
        border: 3px solid green;
    }
    
    .itemMenu {
        text-align: center;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: var(--Gray);
    }
    
    .itemMenu span {
        color: white;
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    
    .itemSubmenu {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .itemMenu:hover>.itemSubmenu {
        display: flex;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 100%;
        background-color: white;
    }
    /* Right DIV  */
    
    .right {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 80%;
    }
    
    .content {
        width: 100%;
        height: 70%;
        background-color: var(--Gray);
        border: 5px solid yellow;
    }
    
    .bottom {
        width: 100%;
        height: 30%;
        background-color: var(--DarkBlue);
        border: 10px solid red;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left">
            <div class="itemMenu">
                <div class="itemSubmenu"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <div class="content"></div>
            <div class="bottom"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: your code is not same as your given images . and specify what is menu ,submenu or else in your image

Comment: i just updated it, can u take a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good day ^^

I've spent a few minutes creating something similar using @keyframes. Unfortunately they are a bit janky for how I used them but it works, here's the code;

```css
*{margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
body{background-color: lightblue;}

/* Menu Area */
.Menus{background-color: darkred; position: fixed; left: 0vw; top: 0px; width: 20vw; height: 100vh; display: grid; grid-template-columns: 100% 0%;}
.Menus:hover{animation: PopOutMenu 0.2s forwards;}

/* Menus */
.Menu1, .Menu2{height: 100%;}
.Menus .Menu1{background-color: red;}
.Menus .Menu2{background-color: orange; color: transparent;}
.Menus .Menu2:hover{animation: DisplayMenu 1s forwards;}

/* Main Content */
.Main{background-color: blue; margin-left: 20vw;}

/* Keyframe Animations */
@keyframes PopOutMenu{
  0%{grid-template-columns: 100% 0%;}
 01%{grid-template-columns: 90% 10%;}
 25%{grid-template-columns: 80% 20%;}
 50%{grid-template-columns: 70% 30%;}
 75%{grid-template-columns: 60% 40%;}
100%{grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;}
}
@keyframes DisplayMenu{
  0%{color: transparent;}
100%{color: black;}
}
```

```html
<body>
<section class="Menus">
    <div class="Menu1">
        <h1>Menu1</h1>
        <a>Link One</a>
        <a>Link Two</a>
        <a>Link Three</a>
    </div>
    <div class="Menu2">
        <h1>Menu2</h1>
        <a>This Page1</a>
        <a>This Page2</a>
        <a>This Page3</a>
    </div>
</section>
<div class="Main">
    <h1>Menu</h1>
    <a>Test</a>
    <a>Test</a>
    <a>Test</a>
</div>
</body>
```

Perhaps this can be helpful to you. Tweak it how you'd like and perhaps change it out for something smoother later.

**Version 2**
I've kept working on it. This is much smoother.

```css
*{margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
body{background-color: lightblue;}
a{display: block;}

/* Menu Area */
.Menus{position: fixed; left: 0vw; top: 0px; width: 20vw; height: 100vh; display: grid; grid-template-columns: 100% 0%;}
.Menus:hover{animation: PopOutMenu 0.25s forwards;}

/* Menus */
.Menu1, .Menu2{height: 100%;}
.Menus .Menu1{background-color: dimgray;}
.Menus .Menu2{background-color: gray; position: absolute; left: 10vw; z-index: -1; width: 50%;}

/* Main Content */
.Main{background-color: blue; margin-left: 20vw;}

/* Keyframe Animations */
@keyframes PopOutMenu{
  0%{grid-template-columns: 100% 0%;}
 10%{grid-template-columns: 95% 05%;}
 20%{grid-template-columns: 90% 10%;}
 30%{grid-template-columns: 85% 15%;}
 40%{grid-template-columns: 80% 20%;}
 50%{grid-template-columns: 75% 25%;}
 60%{grid-template-columns: 70% 30%;}
 70%{grid-template-columns: 65% 35%;}
 80%{grid-template-columns: 60% 40%;}
 90%{grid-template-columns: 55% 45%;}
100%{grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;}
}
```

```html
<body>
<section class="Menus">
    <div class="Menu1">
        <h1>Menu1</h1>
        <a>Link One</a>
        <a>Link Two</a>
        <a>Link Three</a>
    </div>
    <div class="Menu2">
        <h1>Menu2</h1>
        <a>This Page1</a>
        <a>This Page2</a>
        <a>This Page3</a>
    </div>
</section>
<div class="Main">
    <h1>Main Content</h1>
    <h2>Greetings and welcome to our site!</h2>
</div>
</body>
```

Hopefully that can be beneficial to you.